# In Android I am Getting BuildConfig.java but not R.java File

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R.java Missing in Android Project in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133186/r-java-missing-in-android-project-in-netbeans)

In Android I am Getting `BuildConfig.java` file but it can not generate `R.java File`.

Please Help me this regards. I tried with `Android Tool -> fix project properties`. but still failed to run.

I also tried Clean and build but again failed to generate R.Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not "instead of" -- you should have both `BuildConfig.java` and `R.java`. You may have errors in your Eclipse console, or red X marks over a resource (`res/`) or your `AndroidManifest.xml`, that are preventing `R.java` from being rebuilt successfully.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133186/r-java-missing-in-android-project-in-netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when this happens to me, it's because I changed the package= property in the manifest.  This property determines where R.java will be built.  Search your project directory to see if R.java was built at all.  If so, and it's not where your code expected it, you may need to either fix your manifest file, or import it in the code that's referencing it.

If it's not being built at all, try cleaning it as imran suggested.  If that doesn't help, take a good hard look at all your resources. If there's a problem anywhere in the resources, it can prevent R.java from being generated.

Answer (score 1):

try after  deleting  **BuildConfig.java** and **R.java** and rebuild from **Project->Clean...** on Eclipse IDE

Comment: Doesn't work. BuildConfig.java reappears without R.java. It's the xml files that need fixing.